# How can I get array of model's methods names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a possibility in Rails/Ruby to get the list of model's methods. 
fe. ModelName.methods

I want to get all names of methods that belongs to Mailer model.

Comment: In fact what you written exists and is exactly what you want. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorting methods out is always a problem in ruby, because you can't simply say : "give me methods specific to that class".

## Getting methods for a specific class

You have to use array substraction like mentionned by @Monk_Code and even then, you can't separate methods from a base implementation and from its monkey patches.

To exhaustively remove all included modules and all parents methods :

```
> MyClass.instance_methods - ( MyClass.ancestors - [ MyClass ] ).map( &:instance_methods ).flatten
```

Replace `#instance_methods` with `#methods` if you want class methods.

Note that methods dynamically created with `#define_method` in parents like model callbacks will still appear, as they are defined directly on the child class.

## Getting methods for a specific file

Often, isolating methods from a class is not enough.

I wrote an helper that helps me isolate methods from files. It allows to do that :

```
> MyModel.new.located_methods
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                 Name                   |                                                          Location                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| !                                      |                                                                                                                            |
| <=>                                    | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb line 324                                       |
| unloadable                             | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb line 245                             |
| ==                                     | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb line 296                                       |
| validates_format_of                    | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb line 110                           |

| and so on ... |
```

A first parameter allows to grep method names :

```
> MyModel.new.located_methods /validate/
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                        Name                |                                                       Location                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| _validate_callbacks                        | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb line 107           |
| _validate_callbacks=                       | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb line 117           |
| _validate_callbacks?                       | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb line 114           |
| validate_associated_records_for_amenities  | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb line 147                 |
```

And a second one allows to grep per source file :

```
> MyModel.new.located_methods /validate/, /autosave/
+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                        Name                |                                               Location                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| validate_associated_records_for_amenities  | /home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb line 147 |
```

### the code

```
class Object
  # Display an object methods list with their source location.
  #
  # List can optionally be filtered by method pattern and source file
  # pattern.
  #
  # Mainly useful for debugging.
  #
  # @param [Regexp] method_pattern grep method name
  # @param [Regexp] file_pattern grep file name
  def located_methods( method_pattern = nil, file_pattern = nil )
    list = ( method_pattern ? methods.grep( method_pattern ) : methods ).sort.map do |name|
      location = method( name ).source_location
      location = "#{location.first} line #{location.second}" if location
      [ name.to_s.colorize( :yellow ), location ]
    end

    list = list.select { |meth| meth[1] =~ file_pattern } if file_pattern

    puts ( [[ 'Name'.colorize( :yellow ), 'Location' ]] + list ).to_table( first_row_is_head: true )
    true
  end
end
```

This version depends on [colorize](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize) and [text-table](https://github.com/aptinio/text-table), but you can easily modify it to use your preferred way of formatting.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Object
  def show_methods
    (methods - self.class.superclass.instance_methods).sort
  end
end

Mailer.show_methods
```

for example

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use the

```
show-method
```

from the [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry).

You can also navigate within objects like in a unix console via

```
cd
ls
```

etc...

Check out this small [example](http://asciinema.org/a/6392)

and this: http://pryrepl.org/