# How to list the methods only from the included modules

Tags: ruby

I include and extend some modules into my class.

I put binding.pry then  step into it. Use self.methods to list all methods I have.
But the list is too long , How could I list the methods only in the modules I include. Excepts the methods in my self.class and the methods from ancestors like `inspect` `to_s` , ...

```
include SnapshotsHelper
extend SnapshotsHelper
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think something like below you are looking for :

## when you will include modules

```
module A
 def meth1;end
 def meth2;end
end

module B
 def meth11;end
 def meth21;end
end

class C
  include A,B
end

list = C.included_modules.each_with_object({}) do |m,ob|
  module_arry = m.instance_methods
  ob[m]=C.instance_methods.select{|e| module_arry.include?(e)} if m != Kernel
end

p list

# >> {A=>[:meth1, :meth2], B=>[:meth11, :meth21]}
```

## when you will extend modules

```
module A
 def meth1;end
 def meth2;end
end

module B
 def meth11;end
 def meth21;end
end

class C
  extend A,B
end

list = C.singleton_class.included_modules.each_with_object({}) do |m,ob|
  module_arry = m.instance_methods
  class_methods = C.methods - C.instance_methods
  ob[m]= class_methods.select{|e| module_arry.include?(e)} if m != Kernel
end

p list

# >> {A=>[:meth1, :meth2], B=>[:meth11, :meth21]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want only methods from modules included in the very child you're in, filtering out methods from modules included in parents. If you also want modules included from parents, @Arup answer is the good one.

There's no provided core method to do what you want, but you can create one if you need this often.

### Prerequisite knowledge

There are three sources of methods for a given class :

- methods defined in the class itself and its monkey patches
- methods from parent
- methods from modules

Method from modules may be inserted in class itself or from parents (or even by hook in modules, but let's keep that aside).

Note also that Class inherits from Module, so a Class is a Module.

### How to retrieve modules

Now, having all of that, what you want to do is to get all modules included in your current class, remove parent modules and get methods. The basic formula is thus :

```
methods_from_module_included_in_current_class = ( modules_in_class - modules_in_parent ).methods
```

To get all module in class, you can use the `#ancestors` method. It will list all classes and modules which has been mixed in current class (remember : a class is just a module).

```
modules_in_class = MyClass.ancestors.reject { |ancestor| Class === ancestor }
```

Here, we reject what is a Class from the list (`Class === ancestor` is the same than doing `ancestor.is_a? Class`), so we know we only have modules. Again, we can't just select modules, since Class are Module.

Finally, we can apply the same pattern to get modules from parent :

```
module_in_parent = MyClass.superclass.ancestors.reject { |ancestor| Class === ancestor }
```

### Getting methods

So, to get all your methods from modules included in current class :

```
( MyClass.ancestors.reject { |ancestor| Class === ancestor } - MyClass.superclass.ancestors.reject { |ancestor| Class === ancestor } ).map( &:instance_methods ).flatten
```

To get class methods (thus methods added using `#extend`) rather, replace `instance_methods` with `methods`.

Note you may still have a few unfamiliar methods here if some anonymous module is declared on class initialization, like rails does on ActiveRecord::Base.

### Factoring that

If you find yourself using this frequently, you can factorize it in a method :

```
class Object
  def inner_module_methods
    ( self.class.ancestors.reject { |ancestor| Class === ancestor } - self.class.superclass.ancestors.reject { |ancestor| Class === ancestor } ).map( &:instance_methods ).flatten
  end
end
```

You can now do :

```
obj.inner_module_methods
```

Or within pry :

```
inner_module_methods
```

### Alternative

You may also want to [filter methods by source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977432/how-can-i-get-array-of-models-methods-names/19978839#19978839). If find this being more effective and volatile, in the long run.